# Postgress lexeme text-search query contains only stop words or doesn't contain lexemes, ignored

Tags: postgresql

I use full text search with GIN index.

```
create index cn_custom_index on category
using GIN(to_tsvector('english',coalesce(category_name,'')||' '))
```

and when I using `*` - can be attached to a lexeme to specify prefix matching. I have strange behavior, in one case search has result in anouther don't has, but should have. Example I search by `inr:*` and have four result but when I try search by `in:*` I had nothing, empty result, but should get the same result like when I searched with `inr:*`

```
SELECT                         
DISTINCT category_alias.id,
category_alias.category_name AS "category_name",
category_alias.created_at AS "createdAt",
ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english',coalesce(category_name,'')||' '), query_search) AS rank

FROM category category_alias 

JOIN to_tsquery('inr:*') query_search
ON to_tsvector('english',coalesce(category_name,'')||' ') @@ query_search

GROUP BY category_alias.id, query_search.query_search ORDER BY rank DESC, "createdAt" DESC
```

result

```
1320    Inre skönhet    2020-04-21 16:25:17 0.1
195 Inredningsdetaljer  2020-04-02 20:20:10 0.1
62  Inredning   2020-03-27 17:43:15 0.1
9   Hem & inredning 2020-03-27 17:43:11 0.1
```

and search with `in:*`

```
SELECT                         
DISTINCT category_alias.id,
category_alias.category_name AS "category_name",
category_alias.created_at AS "createdAt",
ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english',coalesce(category_name,'')||' '), query_search) AS rank

FROM category category_alias 

JOIN to_tsquery('in:*') query_search
ON to_tsvector('english',coalesce(category_name,'')||' ') @@ query_search

GROUP BY category_alias.id, query_search.query_search ORDER BY rank DESC, "createdAt" DESC
```

with the same behavior I faced when try to search by one symbol, like `f`  return result but with `s` I had othing.

I try to sue `simple` for `to_tsquery`

```
SELECT                         
DISTINCT category_alias.id,
category_alias.category_name AS "category_name",
category_alias.created_at AS "createdAt",
ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('english',coalesce(category_name,'')||' '), query_search) AS rank

FROM category category_alias 

JOIN to_tsquery('simple','s:*') query_search
ON to_tsvector('english',coalesce(category_name,'')||' ') @@ query_search

GROUP BY category_alias.id, query_search.query_search ORDER BY rank DESC, "createdAt" DESC
```

and result appear, but question in this case GIN index works correct ?
Or I should change index to

```
create index cn_custom_index on category
using GIN(to_tsvector('simple',coalesce(category_name,'')||' '))
```

correct ?

Answer (score 0):

to_tsquery applies stop word filtering and stemming even to things with decorated with `:*`.  Arguably it should not do that, but nonetheless that is what it does.

You can get around this by writing the tsquery directly rather than using to_tsquery:

```
JOIN (select 'in:*'::tsquery) query_search(query_search)
```

But perhaps you should instead switch to 'simple' as you suggest, both because prefix searching is inherently problematic when stop words and stemming are in place, and because the things you are searching are clearly not English.